# How do I speed up/slow down audio without changing the pitch, and vice versa?

Tags: unity, audio

Using Unity's own default `AudioSource`, there is a pitch slider. However, that pitch slider affects both the speed and the pitch.

Short of doing the speed up/slow down in an external program and importing multiple versions of the same audio track or using third-party middlewares, is there another way to achieve this in the stock engine?

I'm happy for any guidance towards any APIs to do this programatically (ie. access to the raw soundwave as it's being played*) or concoction of internal components.

*You can access the raw waveform (samples) of an AudioClip, but I prefer to do this real-time.

Comment: Changing pitch without changing playback speed, and vice-versa, is actually a very difficult problem in audio engineering. Such effects are often computationally expensive and still come out sounding artificial - for example, recent AAA game Hogwarts Legacy has a pitch control for the player's voice, and putting the slider to either extreme causes very noticeable digital distortion in the voice. I haven't used it, but you might look at the FMOD plugin for Unity: https://fmod.com/docs/2.02/api/effects-reference.html#pitch-shifter

Comment: Have you looked into [OnAudioFilterRead](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html)?

Comment: The general rule of thumb I use is that if I'm changing the pitch by 10% or less, I can do it with the `pitch` property in Unity and the user won't notice the difference in the length of the clip. Any more than that, and the clip generally needs to be recreated/re-recorded at the desired pitch. You can try to write a custom filter using `OnAudioFilterRead()`, but if you aren't already deeply familiar with audio engineering, you'll probably be overwhelmed.

Comment: @DMGregory That sounds like what I might be looking for; thanks! Only issue is you can't mark a comment as an answer, lol.

Comment: Remember you can answer your own questions. So if you're able to get a working speed adjustment or pitch shift filter using this callback, post your implementation as an answer and you can mark it as Accepted so other folks struggling with the same issue know it successfully solved the problem.